# How HiveContext of spark internally works?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark.I found using `HiveContext` we can connect to `hive` and run `HiveQL`s. I run it and it worked.

My doubt is whether `Spark` does it through `spark jobs` .That is, it uses `HiveContext` only for accessing corresponding hive table files from HDFS

Or

It internally calls hive to execute the query?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, Spark doesn't call the hive to execute query. Spark only reads the metadata from hive and executes the query within Spark engine. Spark has it's own SQL execution engine which includes components such as catalyst, tungsten to optimize queries and give faster results. It uses meta data from hive and execution engine of spark to run the queries.

One of the greatest advantages of Hive is it's metastore. It acts as a single meta store for lot of components in hadoop eco system.

Coming to your question, when you use HiveContext, it will get access to metastore db and all your Hive Meta Data, which can clearly explain what type of data you have , where do you have the data , serialization and deserializations, compression codecs, columns, datatypes and literally every detail about the table and it's data. That is enough for spark to understand the data.

Overall, Spark only needs metastore which gives complete details of underlying data and once it has the metadata, it will execute the queries that you asked for, over its on execution engine. Hive is slower than Spark as it uses MapReduce. So, there is no point in going back to hive and ask to run it in hive.

Let me know if it answers ur question.

Comment: Can you add some documentation references for this please? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer! I also mentioned that SQL queries for small tables work times faster in HiveContext of Spark than executed directly in Hive on Tez. Would be perfect to see some link to source code or documentation where it makes clear that HiveContext uses Spark engine instead of executing queries in Hive itself.

Comment: Why can I not find the documentation in Spark for this?